# hyperledger composer: not able to access attributes of object returned from query

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Within a transaction processor function within my hyperledger composer application I used the following line of code (in order to get the patient with the email address 'adam@gmail.com'):

```
let result = await query('selectPatientByEmail', {
    "email": "adam@gmail.com"    
});
```

The query is defined in the queries.qry file as follows:

```
query selectPatientByEmail {
    description: "Select the patient with the given email address"
    statement:
        SELECT org.comp.app.Patient
            WHERE (email == _$email) }
```

A Patient is defined as follows in the model.cto file:

```
participant Patient identified by id {
  o String id
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o String email
}
```

The problem is this: when I try to access the id of the returned patient, this is not possible. That is, result.id is "undefined"

How can I access the id of the patient returned?

---

This question is related to the following question:
[how to define BusinessNetworkConnection in hyperledger-composer transaction processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479770/how-to-define-businessnetworkconnection-in-hyperledger-composer-transaction-proc?noredirect=1#comment89957676_51480346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember that the results are going to be an array of JS objects.

So you would use a `for` loop to step through the results - then you can acccess any attribute of the object (per your model) eg.

```
let result = await query('selectPatientByEmail', {
    "email": "adam@gmail.com"    
    });

for (var n = 0; n < result.length; n++) {

       console.log("Patient Id is " + result[n].id );
       // alternative : console.log("Patient Id is " + result[n].getIdentifier());
       console.log("Patient Email is " + result[n].email);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had forgotten that it was an array.

Answer (score 0):

The participant Patient that you have defined their is no attribute with name **email**. So The query selectPatientByEmail will always  return the **Empty Object {}**.  When you are calling result.id equivalent to **{}.id** which will be undefined

Comment: In my actual model Patient was inheriting attributes (such as email) from a parent class ... to make things more simple I left away the parent class for this post but forgot to include email in the Patient class .... I corrected this now (see above) ... Sorry about the confusion ...

Comment: What is the your query response.